# What is the best approach to create Constant file in Swift? Please check the description

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, coding-style, constants

I have seen some people declaring constant file using Struct like this:

**Approach 1:**

```
struct Constants {
    struct UserInfoParam {
        static let userName = "user_name"
        static let userID = "user_id"
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
print(Constants.UserInfoParam.userName)
```

**Approach 2:**
And some people directly create a Swift file and simply declare the variables, like:

```
import Foundation

let userName = "user_name"
let userID = "user_id"
```

And call it simply like this:

```
print(userID)
```

I want to know which approach is best to implement for Code Quality and Other Coding aspects. Can someone clarify me this? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you can argue against both styles, so this question is quite opinion based.

Comment: I have marked this question to be closed as its more Opinion based.

P.S: Approach 1 is more clear as you won't have to remember each constant's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding style depends on person to person, so here it also depends on you and your requirement.

For example with **Approach 1**, you can categorize your constants. Check,

```
struct Constants {
    struct UserInfoParam {
        static let userName = "user_name"
        static let userID = "user_id"
    }

    struct API {
        static let api1 = "api1"
        static let api2 = "api2"
    }

    struct AlertMessages {
        static let NoDataFound = "No Data Found."
        static let InternetError = "Check internet connection."
    }

}
```

In the above approach, personally I prefer not to use **Constants** struct, as it just increasing the struct hierarchy.

So I did like this,

```
struct UserInfoParam {
    :
}

struct API {
    :
}

struct AlertMessages {
    :
}
```

Now whenever need I just write `AlertMessages.NoDataFound` instead of `Constants.AlertMessages.NoDataFound`. These both way are correct and you can try anyone.

But when you talked about **Approach2**, then you can use it for some general constants.

For Eg.

```
let Base_URL = "Base URL"
let ItunesAppId = "ID"
```

so on.

These objects globally used, even in the `Constants` struct too. These vars are not belonging to any category.

In these ways generally developer did code.

Comment: From your answer, I can think of using both ways for single constant file, where if I have to categorise the constants I can make struct like 1st approach and if there is only one variable nothing related to any others, then I can use the 2nd approach.

Comment: I would not get too cute dumping everything in one spot. I tend to keep stuff in the neighborhood where it’s used.

Comment: Like @Adrian suggests, it makes sense to keep them as close as possible to the call sites where they're used so it's easier to change their values with minimal cascading issues across other call sites.

But, pragmatically, I will start out using @dahiya_boy's approach: putting it in one file, but not nesting the `struct`s and then when things are clearer to me on the project, I can easily move individual `struct`s to seperate files without breaking references to them.

Answer (score 0):

see apple / swift docs. (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html )
they simply say:

*Declaring Constants and Variables
Constants and variables must be declared before they’re used. You declare constants with the let keyword and variables with the var keyword. Here’s an example of how constants and variables can be used to track the number of login attempts a user has made:*

```
let maximumNumberOfLoginAttempts = 10
var currentLoginAttempt = 0
```

so no need to struct.
Can be questionable if wee have to share const in multiple files...
I will say myst be very few... and public (default access is fine)